# Check existing rows for prediction in one MYSQL request

Tags: php, mysql

(Sorry if the title isn't that clear).

I have a table like this (much more complicated, but enough to explain I think):

```
id    name    hour    was_here
1     John    1       0
2     John    2       1
3     John    3       1
4     Mel     1       1
5     Mel     2       1
6     Mel     3       0
7     Smith   1       1
8     Elton   2       0
```

Let say I'm now at **hour=4** and I would like to know who is supposed to be here.

## Explanation

John was here ont here the forts jour but was here the 2 next hours -> we can suppose he's here.

Mel was here the first two hours, but not the third. As it's the *last* hour before the **hour=4**, we can suppose she won't be here.

Smith was here the first hour, but we don't know for the next two hours -> we can suppose he's here.

Elton was not here the second hour -> as it's the only information we have, we can suppose he won't be here.

## What I'm doing actually

Actually, what I do is checking each name using a query like this:

```
SELECT was_here FROM table WHERE name='$name' AND hour<4 ORDER BY hour DESC
```

And I extract the first row result.

## Finally the question

My question is... can I have this in **one** mysql query ?
It should give me the name of the person that were last detected *not here* and which hour it was.

Result:

```
# -----------------
# name   |   hour
# -----------------
# Mel    |   3
# Elton  |   0
# -----------------
```

Comment: Just found an error: *John was here the 3 hours before -> we can suppose he's here.* should be *John was not here the first hour but was here the two next hours -> we can suppose he's here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to predict whether a person will be here or not. It is important to formulate the rule precisely. So far it seems your rule is:

- If the last information we got on a person is that he/she was here, we expect them to be here still.

The latest information per person is the one for which there is no newer information. The prediction is that "will be here" equals the last "was here":

```
select name, was_here as will_be_here
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable newer_info
  where newer_info.name = mytable.name
  and newer_info.hour > mytable.hour
  and newer_info.hour < 4
)
and hour < 4;
```

Comment: This one is also working for me. Will try to make some test to find the fastest way between the two posts!

Comment: Just saw the comment: your right, some aliases are wrong but are easily corrected.

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes, I messed up the aliases. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @BasilGass FWIW, I'd be surprised if this correlated subquery beats my uncorrelated one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is much more complicated than it needs to be. You just want the status associated with the max recorded hour for each user.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,hour    INT NOT NULL
,was_here INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1     ,'John'    ,1       ,0),
(2     ,'John'    ,2       ,1),
(3     ,'John'    ,3       ,1),
(4     ,'Mel'     ,1       ,1),
(5     ,'Mel'     ,2       ,1),
(6     ,'Mel'     ,3       ,0),
(7     ,'Smith'   ,1       ,1),
(8     ,'Elton'   ,2       ,0);

SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT name
            , MAX(hour) max_hour
         FROM my_table
        GROUP 
           BY name
     ) y
    ON y.name = x.name
   AND y.max_hour = x.hour;

+----+-------+------+----------+
| id | name  | hour | was_here |
+----+-------+------+----------+
|  3 | John  |    3 |        1 |
|  6 | Mel   |    3 |        0 |
|  7 | Smith |    1 |        1 |
|  8 | Elton |    2 |        0 |
+----+-------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this one is working! And I really like how you resumed the situation!!! 

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will need to use `UNION` in this case.
Your query will looks like this:

```
(SELECT hour, was_here FROM table WHERE name='$name' AND hour<4 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT hour, was_here FROM table WHERE name='$name' AND was_here = '0' ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1)
```

In result you have two rows, one row is person that was not here and your query result.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: I can't see how this helps :-$